# How does one combine a dataframe of different sizes....?

Tags: python, dataframe, merge

I am trying to combine a list of projects into a master dataframe and I can't seem to figure out how to merge them together? The frame I generated are of different sizes, but most of the colum names will be the same, with the exception of one or two....

So basically, I am taking a list of project stages like so... (Some of the projects will only have 2 or 3 stages, where others will have 8 or 9 stages..)
example:

```
Stage 1 SUCCESS
stage 2 SUCCESS
stage 3 SUCCESS
stage 4 DELAYED
stage 5 PENDING
```

and, I generate a dataframe like that below in a python loop...

df

```
       project_name    Stage 1    Stage 2     
0      project 1       SUCCESS    DELAYED
```

df

```
       project_name    Stage 1    Stage 2    Stage 3    Stage 4   Stage 5 
0      project-2       NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN       NaN
```

df

```
       project_name    Stage 1    Stage 2    Stage 3    Stage 4   Stage 5   Stage 6    Stage 7   Stage 8
0      project-3       NaN        NaN        STARTED    ABANDONED NaN       NaN        NaN       
    NaN
```

However, I can't seem to figure out how to generate a master dataframe containing all the other frames...

```
# items passed in from other function...
project_data = [('Stage 1','SUCCESS'),('Stage 2','DELAYED')]
project_name = 'project-x' 
project_headers = ['Stage 1','Stage 2','Stage 3','Stage 4','Stage 5','Stage 6']
project_displayname = ''

# Create the pandas DataFrame
try:
    df
except NameError:
    print("Well, 'df' WASN'T defined after all!")
    df = pd.DataFrame( columns = project_headers, index=['0'])
else:
    df = df.reindex(list(range(0, 1))).reset_index(drop=True)
    df['project_name'] = project_name
    df.loc[df.project_name == project_name, "project"] = project_displayname


combined_frame = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['project_name']) # empty frame with one colum for merge
for details in project_data:
    (item, item_status) = details
    if item not in df:
        df[item] = np.nan
    df.loc[df.project_name == project_name, item] = item_status
    print('')
    print('')
    print(df)  
    print('')
```

```
# Which gives us a generated dataframe.... like so... 
#project_name    Stage 1    Stage 2    Stage 3    Stage 4   Stage 5   Stage 6    Stage 7   Stage 8
#project-3       NaN        NaN        STARTED    ABANDONED NaN       NaN        NaN       NaN
```

```
    #final_frame = combined_frame.merge(df, how='left')
    try:
        final_frame = pd.merge(df, combined_frame, how='outer', left_index=True, right_on=combined_frame.iloc[: , -1])
    except IndexError:
        final_frame = df.reindex_axis(df.columns.union(combined_frame.columns), axis=1)

print(final_frame)
```

When I run the code I get the error: Empty DataFrame

Or, I get...

```
Columns: [project, project_name, Stage 1, Stage 2, Stage 3, Stage 4, Stage 5, Stage 6, Stage 7, Stage 8, Stage 9]
Index: []
```

Or I get...

```
Columns: [project, project_name, Stage 1, Stage 2, Stage 3, Stage 4, Stage 5, Stage 6, Stage 7, Stage 8, Stage 9, project_x, project_name_x, Stage 1_x, Stage 2_x, Stage 3_x, Stage 4_x]
Index: []
```

Can someone point out the erros in my ways? Clearly I am missing something?

I would like to try and get an output like this:

```
   project_name    Stage 1    Stage 2    Stage 3    Stage 4   Stage 5   Stage 6    Stage 7   Stage 8
0  project-1       STARTED    NaN        NaN        NaN       NaN       NaN        NaN       NaN
1  project-2       STARTED    STARTED    STARTED    DELAYED   NaN       NaN        NaN       NaN
2  project-3       NaN        NaN        STARTED    ABANDONED NaN       NaN        NaN       NaN
3  project-4       NaN        NaN        STARTED    ABANDONED NaN       STARTED    NaN       NaN
4  project-5       CANCELED   NaN        NaN        NaN       NaN       NaN        NaN       NaN
5  project-6       DELAYED    DELAYED    STARTED    ABANDONED NaN       NaN        STARTED    NaN
```

Thanks in advance,

E

Comment: From @amy989 (not yet enough rep to comment): Do you need all the individual dfs or would one master df be enough?

Comment: Hi, the master is the goal, as I am basically requesting data from serveral servers to make the individual dataframes....  The stage names can be anything, so I am basically piecing together those  individual frames...  I don't know the exact number of  headers I will have... It is passed in as a details tuple.... I have coding to update the stage if the tuple contains that info, else leave it as NaN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily build an individual frame from your *input* data:

```
# items passed in from other function...
project_data = [('Stage 1','SUCCESS'),('Stage 2','DELAYED')]
project_name = 'project-x' 
project_headers = ['Stage 1','Stage 2','Stage 3','Stage 4','Stage 5','Stage 6']
project_displayname = ''

df = pd.DataFrame([dict(project_data)], columns = ['project','project_name']
                  + project_headers)
df.loc[:, ['project', 'project_name']] = [[project_name, project_displayname]]
```

It will give for `df`:

```
     project project_name  Stage 1  Stage 2  Stage 3  Stage 4  Stage 5  Stage 6
0  project-x               SUCCESS  DELAYED      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
```

You can then use `pd.concat` to concatenate all the individual dataframes. The only limitation is that you must know in advance the names for all the columns (or here the maximum number of stages...)

Comment: This is a great example "Serge" unfortunatly the data that is passed in is in a tuple and I don't have a block of headers to use. I am simply peicemealing it together.... The only certainty I have is the project_name and project_displayname. The stage names are added from a details tuple and I condition the data into it. I am not certain all stages will be penent. I tried doing a concat with a guess of the last colum, but that didn't work out well for me either... So I tried mashing it together, but in reality, I was only able to mash the hearders into a list, but no data....

Comment: @Mr.E : I can only use what you show :-( . More seriously, both the dataframe constructor and `pd.concat` can happily process rows having additional columns. What matters now is the way you *really* get the input data, and to make sure of the actual robustness, the magnitude order of the total number of rows that you will concatenate in the final dataframe.

Comment: Appologies for the trouble and lack of information. The long and the short of it is I have I assembled the dataframes for each project  outlined as "df" in the question. It is assembled in a for loop, so I just have to find a way to use that looping to build the master dataframe.

Comment: @Mr.E: Then you should gather the dataframe for each project in a mere Python list, and then call `pd.concat` on that list... It worked in a trivial test, but I could not test it on **your** real data...